# PHP adding a filter to an image issues

Tags: php, image-processing

Having afew problems with converting an image to greyscale, see below code:

```
<?php
//Apply photo effects, load images using their ID from database
function applyEffect($id) {
    //Check if passed variable is an array
    if(gettype($id)=="array") {

    }

    //Testing
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg("http://localhost:1234/ppa/data/images/18112013/0/image2.jpg");
    if($img && imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE)) {
        echo "Image converted to greyscale!";
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($img);

        imagedestroy($img); 
    }
}

applyEffect(0);
?>
```

This simply produces the following, see top left of the printscreen below,as you can see it's producing the "broken image link" image.

[image: uhoh]

If I use this code below to actually save the photo, I simply get an error:

```
<?php
//Apply photo effects, load images using their ID from database
function applyEffect($id) {
    //Check if passed variable is an array
    if(gettype($id)=="array") {

    }
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg("http://localhost:1234/ppa/data/images/18112013/0/image2.jpg");

    //Testing
    if($img && imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE)) {
        echo "Image converted to greyscale!";

        imagejpeg($img,"C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\data\images\18112013\0\image2_grey.jpg"); // <--- line 14

        imagedestroy($img); 
    }
}

applyEffect(0);
?>
```

Error:

> Warning: imagejpeg(C: mpp\htdocs\ppa\data\images8112013): failed to
>   open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line
>   14

**Edit:**
May as well use same thread. Let's say I want to send the effect through a function argument, can I also send the additional arguments through that as well, can't really explain it, here is how I would imagine it.

```
<?php
//Apply photo effects
function applyEffect($url,$effect) {
    //List valid effects first


    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);

    //Testing
    if($img && imagefilter($img, $effect)) {
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($img);

        imagedestroy($img); 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

applyEffect("http://localhost:1234/ppa/data/images/18112013/0/image3.jpg",IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS[20]);
?>
```

As you can see I pass IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS through the function arguments, but the filter i'm using needs an additional argument which it would be nice to send when I call the applyEffect function, like so: IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS[20]

But this does not work, any pointers?

Comment: My guess is, it did not read the image. Were you able to display the image that is read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are corrupting your image:

```
    echo "Image converted to greyscale!";  <---this line
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($img);
```

You can **NOT** have **ANY** output of any sort before a header() call. The header call is therefore being ignored utterly. The echo's output also becomes **PART** of the jpg data output by imagejpeg(). You're probably loading this output into an `<img>` tag in a browser, which is expecting to see an image. e.g. a JPEG starts with two hex digits, `0xFF 0xD8`, but since you're dumping out some plain text, your jpeg image actually starts with

```
Image converted to greyscale!0xFF0xD8
```

and cannot be interpreted by the browser as a valid image, because the image data is NOT where it should be - it's got garbage before it.

As for your second code, you're simply ASSUMING that `imagecreatefromjpeg` actually succeeded - you're loading a remote resource. If it's not present, you don't get a jpeg and are trying to create a GD handle from an invalid source. You then blindly use this non-handle in further operations, which cannot possibly succeed because everything was broken from the start.

Never EVER assume success when dealing with remote resources: database calls, HTTP requests, etc... Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise

Comment: See updated post, just another quick question, and thanks by the way.